# How to display a maintenance screen when the server is down?

Tags: dns, failover, maintenance-mode

In the rare case the server is down, I want to display a friendly screen for users. I will host the page on an other provider.

What is the recommended DNS configuration for that?

Answer (score 1):

DNS is not the best instrument for fail-over setups, due to its operation being designed around caching. Once a record from a zone of yours has been read from one of your authoritative servers, it will be cached elsewhere, and not re-requested for some time. Even though you have some control over that caching time, there are limits to the effects of shortened caching time - recursive nameservers or caching forwarders may simply ignore your request for a too short caching period, and substitute against their own default, which they then consider more reasonable.  The proper balance between low TTL (resulting in general slow-down resolving hosts from your zone, and increased load on server) and interval until traffic goes to your second server is hard to strike, therefore i'd be looking for other solutions than trying to solve that using DNS

Comment: any clue where to look for alternative solution ?